# PyInstaller error when running exe with TensorFlow2 and Tkinter libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, tensorflow2.0

I have a small application on Tkinter that uses the TensorFlow2 library. I'm running `pyinstaller main2.py` and the project is successfully built, but when you run it through the console, you get this:

```
C:\Users\pikro\PycharmProjects\NeuralStyleTransfer\dist\main2>main2.exe
2020-05-24 15:48:27.175935: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-05-24 15:48:27.180194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:489: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\experimental\nn\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\audio_microfrontend_op.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 58, in load_op_library
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: C:\Users\pikro\PycharmProjects\NeuralStyleTransfer\dist\main2\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\_audio_microfrontend_op.so not found
[9892] Failed to execute script main2
```

How can I fix this error?

My imports:

```
from tkinter import *
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
```

Comment: it looks like your script should get some data from the file along the path ```C:\Users\pikro\PycharmProjects\NeuralStyleTransfer\dist\main2\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\_audio_microfrontend_op.so```
but there it is not, and an exception is thrown

Comment: and what to do then?

Comment: insert the desired file into place and everything should work

Comment: and where should I look for him?  And in my tensorflow folder only python folder

Comment: here ```C:\Users\pikro\PycharmProjects\NeuralStyleTransfer\dist\main2\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\_audio_microfrontend_op.so```

Comment: if you want more help, you need to publish the code, the information provided is not enough

Comment: can you upload an image for content_image or i can you use any?

Comment: Well, in the IDE, yes, it turns out the path to the image is entered in the field

Comment: C:\Users\pikro\PycharmProjects\NeuralStyleTransfer\dist\main2\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops does this directory exist?

Comment: What do you enter in the program window, specifically?

Comment: path to image, but I cant compile it to exe. there is no such directory, only in tensorflow folder python folder

Comment: it looks like these are problems with tensorflow, first try reinstalling tensorflow and recompiling everything you need, and if that doesn't work, ask the question here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Comment: OK, Now reinstall tensorflow. I have version 2.2.0

Comment: `File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\envs\style_transfer2\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pikro\anaconda3\envs\style_transfer2\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package` tf 2.0.0

Comment: My python code (a.py) has only one line i.e., import tensorflow as tf                          and get the error                                                                                                   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded                                                              Projects/TF21/a$ pyinstaller a.py
26 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
26 INFO: Python: 3.6.9
26 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.3.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
26 INFO: wrote /home/TF/Projects/TF21/a/a.spec
27 INFO: UPX is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create new conda env, install tensorflow v2.1.0, created a file hook-tensorflow.py and moved it to PyInstaller

Comment: Post the contents of the `hook-tensorflow.py`

Comment: `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all


def hook(hook_api):
    packages = [
        'tensorflow',
        'tensorflow_core',
        'astor'
    ]
    for package in packages:
        datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(package)
        hook_api.add_datas(datas)
        hook_api.add_binaries(binaries)
        hook_api.add_imports(*hiddenimports)`